# SVG mapping in Qt

Tags: image, qt, svg, mapping

I have a map of a location. I need to create an SVG file containing different mapped regions. i.e. I want to define multiple polygons on the map, and have a mapping of their coordinates. Then what I need to do is be able to manipulate that file in Qt.

ex: I take an image from google earth and I draw a polygon for my pool, and a polygon for my house. Using Qt's SVG module, I want to be able to access those polygons I created, along with their coordinates, like a QGraphicsItem for instance.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: Do you want your app to create the SVG file, or edit it, or both?

Comment: I will be using a commercially available tool to create the file. I just need the app to be able to read it and recognize the different 'regions' or 'objects' I've defined.

Comment: Do you need editing capabilites, something like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)? I'm not sure how to manage that offhand, but if you just need to get access to the elements, you could work with the SVG's dom directly and paint the updated SVG onto a widget using `QSvgRenderer` or just `QSvgWidget`. I've never tried it, but could a `QDomDocument` be used to parse the SVG's DOM? Perhaps...